# Android Image Intent from URL to Browser or other activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to have an image open from a URL to an intent, most likely the browser or maybe a picture previewer like the one built into twidroyd.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/earth/gal_new-zealand.jpg");

intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivity(intent);
```

However when I try, I get the following exception:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
>   No Activity found to handle Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT
>   dat=http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/earth/gal_new-zealand.jpg
>   typ=image/* }

I've gotten plain URLs to open to the browser. I just can't figure out what action or category to specify, I've tried:

```
intent.addCategory("CATEGORY_BROWSABLE");
// and
intent.addCategory("CATEGORY_OPENABLE");
```

It also doesn't work if I set the action as:

```
android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the mime type might make the Intent matcher a little too specific based on how the browser sets up its filters. Trying using `ACTION_VIEW`, with the uri as data and do not set the mime type.

Comment: I should have just stuck with doing what I did for other urls. I thought maybe images would be handled special. Thanks!